# Getting all chatter groups into a page

Tags: apex, chatter, connect-api

How can I leverage standard chatter page functionality to show all chatter groups in my org? If you click on chatter, then groups, you see a list of all available groups... as shown below[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Connect In Apex for this

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterGroups_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterGroups_getGroups

Use getGroups to return the Group Page

```
public static ConnectApi.ChatterGroupPage getGroups(String communityId, Integer pageParam, Integer pageSize)
```

Pass Community Id as null if you are viewing this page outside community

Comment: then iterate over them using apex repeat? what about if i want to have the request to join capability as well? Just use command button and use the connect api?

Comment: yes .You may like to build a simplified wrapper class out of return from connect api.The return objects from connect api are little complex